# Changing User in MVC 2 MockHttpContext breaks Test?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, tdd

I changed the following line:

```
private readonly IPrincipal _user = 
       new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("someUser"), null /* roles */);
```

to

```
 private readonly IPrincipal _user = 
       new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("realUser"), null /* roles */);
```

and the following test broke, but I am not sure why and I am not sure how to trace it.  I am new to TDD

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ChangePassword_Post_ReturnsRedirectOnSuccess()
    {
        // Arrange
        AccountController controller = GetAccountController();
        ChangePasswordModel model = new ChangePasswordModel()
        {
            OldPassword = "goodOldPassword",
            NewPassword = "goodNewPassword",
            ConfirmPassword = "goodNewPassword"
        };

        // Act
        ActionResult result = controller.ChangePassword(model);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
        RedirectToRouteResult redirectResult = (RedirectToRouteResult)result;
        Assert.AreEqual("ChangePasswordSuccess", redirectResult.RouteValues["action"]);
    }
```

An explanation of how this works and why changing someUser to realUser would break the above test would be very helpful.

Comment: What broke specifically?  The test threw an error, or what assert failed?  Also, is the change password action the same as the default provided one?

Comment: This assert failed:

Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected type:<System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult>. Actual type:<System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult>.

The Change Password action is the default one provided.  The only thing I changed was the string "someUser" to "realUser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests the login failed. You can confirm this by debugging the test and tracing through  `controller.ChangePassword(model);`. Testing any action involving authentication requires mocking or replacing the membership provider.